# FME Server fails some jobs due to not being able to read SDE file but others succeed

Tags: fme

looking for some FME help if anyone can. I am having a bit of an issue where I am running a workspace through FME server to turn GML into single line sql using a GEODATABASE_SDE writer. Have a few other workbenches doing same thing for different data sets and they work fine. This particular one however runs 21 jobs in server reading in the different files, 2 succeed and write features to the sql database, 19 fail with

> An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the connection
>   parameters from the connection file

I can't figure out why it would work for 2 (different 2 each time) and not the others. The SDE file works fine in Arc Catalogue to connect to the DB.

I have tried rebuilding the writers to make sure that they were pointing at the right SDE connection and did not have some reference to an old one left.

Has anyone encountered this before or have any ideas on what is causing this? Thanks in advance for any help